# Chamada de métodos da Classe em Python

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um trabalho de um jogo de baralho e estou tendo um problema ao chamar os métodos da classe `Deck()`, já tentei refazer algumas partes do código e as vezes da como objeto não definido, refiz novamente e mesmo assim nada, alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda se possível ? agradeço desde já.

Segue o código:

```
  import random
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def getRankeado(self):
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):
         return self.suit


class Deck:
    ranks = {'2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A'}

    suits = {'ZAP', 'COPAS', 'OURO', 'ESPADA'}

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []

        for suit in Deck.suits:
            for rank in Deck.ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(rank, suit))

    def dealCard(self):
        return self.deck.pop()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__repr()

    def lenDeck(self):
        return self.len(Deck)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def imprime(self):
        return print(self.Deck, self.Card)

#saidas

c = Deck()
c.shuffle()
c2 = c.dealCard()
c2.getRank(), c2.getSuit()
```

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Na saida do programa, fiz mais algumas alterações no código

Comment: Resolveu? se sim publique a solução.

Comment: AInda não consegui resolver, quando passo o getTank() e o getSuit() em cima do objeto c2 ele não me retorna nada.

Answer (score 1):

Você reparou que o método `getRank()` estava grafado como `getRankeado()`? Após a correção o seu programa passa a funcionar corretamente:

```
import random

class Card(object):

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def getRank(self):
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):
         return self.suit

# ... Class Deck() ...

c = Deck()
c.shuffle()
c2 = c.dealCard()

print(c2.getRank(), c2.getSuit())
```

Acrescentei este **print** na última linha para exibir os valores da carta escolhida.

Comment: Boa tarde Giovanni,  desculpe a demora para responder, consegui solucionar o problema, o problema era que estava pegando a referencia somente do objeto pois o método repr estava errado e fiz as alterações que me passou também,  obrigado pela atenção e pela dicas.